# Rota com parametros URL Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-rotas

é uma pergunta boba, mas estou quebrando a cabeça e não saio do lugar.

Tenho a url

> subcategoria/sessao/3/1/Facirolli04

onde são da seguinte maneira,

> 3 - seria a categoria
>
> 1 - seria a sessão
>
> Facirolli04 - seria o produto

Meu controller esta da seguinte maneira

```
public function sessao($caregoria_id, $id, $nome)
{
    
    $categorias = Categorias::select()->get();
    $produtos = Produtos::select()
                    ->where('sessao_id', $id)
                    ->with('categoria')
                    ->with('sessao')
                    ->inRandomOrder()
                    ->paginate($this->totalPaginas);
    

    $sessoes = Sessoes::select()->where('categoria_id', $nome)->get();
    return view('home.sessao', compact('categorias', 'produtos', 'sessoes'));
```

Minha rota

```
$this->get('produtos/subcategoria/sessao/{categoria_id}/{id}/{nome}', 'Site\SiteController@sessao')->name('site.home.sessao');
```

Onde posso estar errando, pois ele recupera o {id} e o {nome} mas não o {categoria_id}

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um erro de digitação. Note que na declaração do método no controller você tem: `$caregoria_id` ao invés de `$categoria_id`

Comment: Salvador @joaopedrohenrique cara depois de passar a tarde inteira querendo arrumar isso... era um erro bobo... muito obrigado!